# Temporary help message for page on mobile?

Tags: mobile, help

I have screen which needs to explained with a **small temporary help message**. It **shouldn't be a dialog** and should be **least intrusive**.

It only appears when that screen is first opened. I have seen many apps show help guides for buttons with a chat cloud or images which point to that button with an explanation. In my case, I don't have a single button, rather a whole screen that needs to be explained.

This is what I came up with:

[image: Help message]

Any suggestions for improvements or alternatives would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what the message means actually. I think you are explaining the selection of the fields. Is that right? Why don't you explain the fields, close to the fields?

Comment: Just the first paragraph(of the message) explains what this screen is about. The rest is some random text.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called [Onboarding](https://blinkux.com/blog/up-running-3-tips-for-an-awesome-onboarding-ux/),

> Onboarding is a human resources term that we in the UX field have
>   borrowed as a label for the process of getting someone “up and
>   running” with your site, app, or service. The onboarding process is a
>   critical step in setting your users up for success with your product,
>   but there are a number of considerations and hard decisions to be made
>   when you are designing your onboarding to define how best to get your
>   users familiar with your product and its value.

For example, the first couple of times the app is used you will display that help text as per your design. After this initial period you do not need to show this help text again.

However, it might be a good idea to provide a help icon, which when clicked will now recall that help text again - just in case the person needs some refresher about what to do on this page (this all depends on how often this app is used).